# How to convert Blender blend (or obj) file to Qualcom Vuforia .h file

Tags: ios, opengl-es, 3d, blender, vuforia

I'm developing an iOS app with augmented reality using Qualcomm Vuforia and I have difficulty in understanding how to create 3D models from Blender (or other softwares). All the examples use .h files with the coordinates of the vertices to generate i.e. a teapot.
I can not find documentation useful for me.
Is there a tool to convert .blend or .obj files to .h (OpenGL ES)?

thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I developed a script called [**mtl2opengl**](https://github.com/ricardo-rendoncepeda/mtl2opengl) that does exactly what you need, based on the project [obj2opengl](http://heikobehrens.net/2009/08/27/obj2opengl/). The script works with **.obj** and .mtl files, which I think can be exported straight from Blender, and produces **.h** files with vertex data. I use it extensively in my iOS augmented reality applications (though I haven't used the Vuforia SDK yet) and the accompanying resources include a sample Xcode project too. Hope it helps!

Comment: After finally using the Vuforia SDK, I can confirm that my script definitely works with it! I might even make a further project integrating the two.

Comment: Hi. I need to create a .h file from .3ds file. Is it possible? Please help.

Comment: I've never used 3ds Max, but a quick look at the [docs](http://docs.autodesk.com/3DSMAX/16/ENU/3ds-Max-Help/index.html?url=files/GUID-437051A1-983B-4B6A-80C4-D2FA43B7393D.htm,topicNumber=d30e125257) suggests that you can definitely export .3ds to .obj. If you then run the .obj with my script, you should get your .h file :)

Comment: I ran this but it didnt include normal data for some reason, will edit this post if I find a solution to get it to work correctly.

Comment: I'll be updating the script/project soon, and i'll pay extra attention to this if there's an issue.

Comment: Hi I used your script to convert .obj file to .h. But I need to create a MeshObject for my Android app. It requires indices. How to achieve this? Anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 5):

You should check out BlenderVuforiaExport (developed by a coworker of mine) here:

https://github.com/StickyBeat/BlenderVuforiaExport

It exports objects from Blender to the same .h-format used in the Vuforia example project.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about vufoia, but here are two answers about using blender to get 3d models and displaying them on iPhone. These may help you.

[How to get proper number of vertices in OBJ file from DCC tools such as Blender for use in OpenGL ES?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5054239/how-to-get-proper-number-of-vertices-in-obj-file-from-dcc-tools-such-as-blender/5054603#5054603)

[Put a Cinema 4D model and Texture into an iPhone App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5214904/put-a-cinema-4d-model-and-texture-into-an-iphone-app/5263836#5263836)